Renders, cycles - strange noise on textures with bump applied
I've noticed strange noise forming bigger spots. It's only in these places where I've applied bump textures. I tried to increase max samples, decrease bump strength, decrease noise threshold. Looking back, I've found it also on my old renders in different scenes with different settings, HDRI's etc.
Can someone think up what can it be caused by?


Here's the HDRI

I rendered your project as is, and didn't get any of those noise issues.  However, I did notice you have a relatively low resolution render given the amount of detail in that cushion.  I rendered it out at 300%, and it looked great.

Thank you! Although I've tried to render 200% (300% was too much for my computer) with 4096 samples (8192 its almost the same) i still have noise. I've attached an image wihout denoising (after denoising its of course better but far from looking great). In the middle and at right part - its ok but left side of image is strange.

Blender tries to use adaptive sampling by default.  That is, it guesses the amount of noise in an area, and gives it more or less samples based on that.
The purpose of this is to save time by not oversampling an area that has little or no noise.In the case of materials with fine patterns, it tends to look like noise, messing up Blender's guesses.Without having your file, it's hard to know, but I think this is likely your problem.
To fix this, disable "Noise Threshold" for Render.

